# azure data factory - data flow source file error

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a data flow within a foreach loop. It loops through pipe delimited txt files in azure storage, configured the storage as block blob and used identity management as a way for my data factory resource to connect to storage account, i made sure it had all necessary access to the storage account. The pipeline and files got processed/ran fine until last week. All of a sudden this week, i started getting the below error. The Data flow runs for about 15 minutes and throws this error. I made sure the latest file is of the same old format. Anyone faced this issue?

{"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: at Source 'sourcefiles': Status code: -1 error code: null error message: InvalidAbfsRestOperationExceptionjava.net.UnknownHostException: stroageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net","Details":"at Source 'sourcefiles': Status code: -1 error code: null error message: InvalidAbfsRestOperationExceptionjava.net.UnknownHostException: stroageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net"}

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to microsoft support and they asked me to change the Azureblob storage authentication method from managedidentity to Accountkey method and it worked.